# What is the easiest way to convert a lot of PNG images to the DDS format?

Tags: gimp

I have to convert 50+ PNG files to DDS files including mipmaps with no compression.
What is the easiest (quickest) way to do it ?

I can manually open each file in the image processing software Gimp and convert them one by one.. I know it is possible to create batches for this in Gimp : has anyone already written such a script ?

Alternatively, do you know of any tool that would better fit the job ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally a friend told me about DirectX's Texconv.exe tool.
It worked great.